# Pack and expose react components in webpack based on filesystem information

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net

I am using reactjs.net with Webpack and I am trying to load all components which are in the same folder/subfolder as my index.js

```
//Components/index.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var process = require("process");
var directory = __dirname;

function addFile(file, path, exports) {
  if (!file.endsWith(".jsx")) return exports;
  exports[file.substring(0,file.length-4)] = require(path);
  return exports;
}
function addFolder(dir, exports) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        files.forEach(function (file, index) {
            var currentPath = path.join(dir, file);
                fs.stat(dir, function (error, stat) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error("Error stating file.", error);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stat.isFile())
                        exports = addFile(file, currentPath, exports);
                    else if (stat.isDirectory())
                        exports = addFolder(currentPath, exports);

                });
            });
            return exports;
        });
    }
module.exports = addFolder(directory, {});
```

index.js is then required as following:

```
//Content/client.js
var Components = require('expose-loader?Components!./../Components');
```

Naturally Webpack just packs the whole addFolder function into the output, which of course will not work on the client side. Obviosuly I would want to execute the code in index.js, so now I am curious how I can load all my components without manually stating and expose them globally in the Components object while using the file name as identifier.

Comment: I do not need an answer anymore, as I do not need to expose all Components, just only some as entry points which is not that painful to do by hand.